# Where is MSTest V2

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mstest

I can't seem to find this. Specifically, what I'm looking for is the ability to use `[DataTestMethod]` and `[DataRow]` attributes in my unit tests. I have Visual Studio Professional 2015 installed and I cannot seem to find these attributes in my installation. I've run the setup to see if there's something I'm missing and I can't see anything missing that might contain it.

According to this Microsoft page: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/visualstudioalm/2016/06/17/taking-the-mstest-framework-forward-with-mstest-v2/

"...you can start using it right away (with Visual Studio 2015 itself) with these steps:"

"Install the “MSTest V2” TestFramework as before i.e. look for, and install the framework package as shown below:"

It's unclear what "as before" refers to. I can't find MSTest V2 for installation anywhere.

Right above the quote above, is this 5th step:

`(5) Delivered as a NuGet package.`

Yet I can find no NuGet package for MS Test V2.

What's the deal? Seems this ought to be ridiculously simple to do and yet I'm totally stumped.

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestFramework/1.0.1-preview

Comment: Yes that package has the version "1.x" but so do the images in the MSDN post.

Comment: @vcsjones Thank you! Please make that the answer and I'll give it to you. I had to do it from the console instead of the Packages for Solutions. Not sure why, but it just wouldn't come up in searches. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use this NuGet package:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestFramework/1.0.1-preview

Even though the package has the version number "1.x", this appears to be the package that the announcement is referring to.

Answer (score 2):

To be specific :

- Documentation : https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx-docs
- Product repository : https://github.com/Microsoft/testfx
- **NuGet** : https://www.nuget.org/packages/MSTest.TestFramework/

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)